# How do I extract only the specific string I want from the string?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I would like to extract only `/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin` from the code string below. What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
 int main(){
    char str[1024]="\r\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";
    char *ptr = strtok(str + 1, "\r");
    strcpy(str, ptr + 1);
    ptr = strtok(str, "\r\n\033");
    printf("%s\n",ptr);
    return 0;
 }
```

The execution result of the code I made is as follows.

> root@audit:~# ./test

> output : [?2004l

Comment: By looking for the first `'/'` (with `strchr`) and the last `'/'` (with `strrchr`) and working with those indexes, plus the next "word"?

Comment: Clever to skip over the first '\r' to find the next one. Sadly, `strtok()` returns the beginning of the segment you've stepped over, not the next segment that you seem to want... Consider switching to `strchr()`...

Comment: When you print the string you found, which contains embedded CR, the next part of the output will overwrite the first part, which you won't see. So in my `strchr` solution the first part `"/home/user01\r"` isn't visible in the output unless I replace the CR with, say, a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` replaces the first delimiter found with the null-terminating byte, and returns the token that precedes it.

Additionally, `strtok` does not handle empty tokens, treating a series of adjacent delimiters as a single delimiter.

The following

```
/* first CR removed, as is the effect of the first `strtok` and `strcpy` in the example */
char str[] = "\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";
char *token = strtok(str, "\r\n\033")
```

results in a null-terminating byte being placed in `str` and `token` being equal to `str + 2`

```
/* start of token --v      v-- NUL byte */
char str[] = "\n\033[?2004l\0/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";
```

---

Here are a couple of naive examples that work with the **exact** string in question.

Using [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) and [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "\r\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";

    char *base = strchr(str, '/');
    char *tail = strstr(base, "\r\n");

    /* for printing purposes remove the CR */
    *strchr(base, '\r') = '_';

    printf("%.*s\n", (int) (tail - base), base);
}
```

Using [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) and [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "\r\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";

    char *base = strchr(str, '/');
    size_t length = strcspn(base, "\n");

    /* for printing purposes remove the CR */
    *strchr(base, '\r') = '_';

    /* `length - 1` removes the trailing CR */
    printf("%.*s\n", (int) (length - 1), base);
}
```

Both of these find the span of characters (`'\r'` replaced with `'_'` for display purposes):

```
/home/user01_uuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

---

Note that `strchr` and `strstr` can return `NULL`, and passing `NULL` to any of these functions results in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). `strcspn` can obviously return `0`, in which case subtracting one from this value would result in [`SIZE_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits). These situations should all be considered and guarded against in a real program.

Answer (score 1):

**Undefined behavior**

`strcpy(str, ptr + 1);` is (UB) is it attempts to copy a string where the source and destination overlap.  Don't do that.

```
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

The `restrict` in `strcpy()` implies the caller should not pass in pointers to overlapping areas.

---

Research `strspn()` and `strcspn()` as a replacement for `strtok()`.  Used as pair, they work like `strtok()` without changing the source string.

*Something* like below.  Notice that the `str[1024]` is even `const`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char str[1024] =
      "\r\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";
  const char *start1 = str + 1;

  const char *token = "\r";
  const char *end1 = start1 + strcspn(start1, token);
  printf("%.*s\n", (int) (end1 - start1), start1);
  const char *start2 = end1 + strspn(end1, token);

  const char *end2 = start2 + strcspn(start2, token);
  printf("%.*s\n", (int) (end2 - start2), start2);
  const char *start3 = end2 + strspn(end2, token);

  token = "\r\n\033";
  const char *end3 = start3 + strcspn(start3, token);
  printf("%.*s\n", (int) (end3 - start3), start3);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
[?2004l
/home/user01
uuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

---

Or perhaps with a loop?

```
int main(void) {
  const char str[1024] =
      "\r\n\033[?2004l\r/home/user01\ruuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin\r\n\033[?2004h\033]0;user01@audit: ~\auser01@audit:~$ ";
  const char *token = "\r\n\033";

  const char *ptr = str;
  size_t offset;
  while ((offset = strspn(ptr, token)) != 0) {
    const char *start = ptr + offset;
    const char *end = start + strcspn(start, token);
    printf("%.*s\n", (int) (end - start), start);
    ptr = end;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
[?2004l
/home/user01
uuidd:x:108:114::/run/uuidd:/usr/sbin/nologin
[?2004h
]0;user01@audit: ~user01@audit:~$
```